# Using data.table's fast expand grid CJ does not work when a sublists is integer 0

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large list with many sublists, each of the sublists is formed by a vector of values. To this list I aim to apply a form of fast expand grid cJ, however when confronted with one of the lists yielding integer zero the function fails. My question is how could I convert Z as per all sublists which yield integer zero are transformed into class which can be submitted to the below function. I know I could use length(Z[[4]) but I aim to have a method that can be used for lists wich may include thousands of lines and a few of them may be integer 0, so I aim to convert in Z any possible integers which may be listed.

```
Z <- list (c(1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2),c(1,2,3,4),c(5,6,4),c(integer(0))) 
do.call ( CJ , args = Z )  # get all combinations
```

My question is if there is any way to change the class as a whole of Z as to succeed in sumitting the data as for the function to work and not yield an error.

```
# Desired Output will be equal to having the last list with a numeric 0 so it will be represented in the fast expand.grid. 
Z <- list (c(1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2),c(1,2,3,4),c(5,6,4),c((0)))
do.call(CJ,Z)
```

Comment: Maybe `do.call(CJ,Z[lengths(Z)>0])`

Comment: @ Nicola this will exclude all lists wich are integer 0, I aim to have the list but with a zero instead

Comment: Not much clear. If a component of the list has zero elements, than the cross join should have zero length. If you want to replace the components without elements with component having one element which is 0, then try: `do.call(CJ,"[<-"(Z,lengths(Z)==0,0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CJ` function comes from `data.table` so it is worth to add that tag to question.

There is an [open FR to create `CJ` generic method](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1090), so it could handle different types separately.
Below the function which address your question.

```
library(data.table)
f = function(x){
    stopifnot(is.list(x))
    ll = sapply(x, length)
    if(any(ll == 0L)) x[ll == 0L] = 0L
    do.call(CJ, args = x)
}
x = list(c(1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2),c(1,2,3,4),c(5,6,4),c(integer(0)))
f(x)
```

Comment: , see desired output. your answer provides an empty table while the table should be as in desired output.

Comment: @Barnaby so you are asking for a different function than `CJ` which is cross join, which by definition should return 0 rows for any length 0 element. I will modify answer to meet your desired output but be aware it is not a `CJ` any more.

Comment: However in the example I provide all list have elements, the need is to substitute integer 0 in Z for 0 in that list. Appologies for the confusion